# GMail API / OAUTH2 - How To Send Emails With Traditional C# SMTP Method Being Deprecated?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

As per notice from Google's [Less Secure App Deprecation Notice](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), on May 30, 2022 the ability access Google accounts through 'less secure apps' is being deprecated. The C# code below is how I have been sending emails from my own personal GMail account. I only send emails from my app. I do not do anything else (read emails, create drafts, etc...) from this account, only sending. Basically, it is the equivalent of sending "no-reply" emails.

```
// C# code
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpDomain, SmtpPortNumber))
{
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = UseDefaultCredentials;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUsername, SmtpPassword);

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage { /* ... */ };
    
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

I've started looking at Google's API and OAuth documentation but I feel like I am going down a dark rabbit hole here since I am not wanting to access other users data, just only send emails from my own account. I assume from research that OAuth2 is the preferred way to do things when at all possible but I can't find a clear cut of example of "if you are doing it this way now", "then start doing this way". Can someone point me to the absolute starting point of the path I need to take to update my code so that I can continue sending emails from my own personal account/app?

Comment: It's talking about using an App Password rather than using your Google Account password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your google account and create an [apps password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) once this is created just use that instead of the actual password for your gmail account.

[Security](https://myaccount.google.com/security)

[image]

```
// C# code
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpDomain, SmtpPortNumber))
{
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = UseDefaultCredentials;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUsername, appsPasswrod);

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage { /* ... */ };
    
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. The "apps password" page you linked does regard that "app passwords aren't recommended" but if my trip down the OAuth2 path fails, I will resort to this as a backup.

Comment: Xoath2 will require that your app be verified it will be harder

Comment: So as it turns out your suggestion was indeed what I had to do as Google does not let you use a server to server "service" account to access the GMail APIs, even if you are only accessing your own account. So I had to use an app password instead but at least with that, I now have a base understanding of OAuth2 practices, so that avenue was not a total dead end.

Comment: Gmail api only allows for service accounts with google workspace accounts.   other wise you need to use Oauth2 and authorize the user once.